# Do these have the same meaning: "I don't like it when she combs my hair!" vs "I don't like her combing my hair!"

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

This is from an English cartoon on youtube [I Don't Want to Comb My Hair!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQ2K1XTCusc) It is about a little princess who hides combs from the nanny because she doesn't want her hair to be combed by her.

Mother: Princesses must comb their hair.

Princess: **But I don't like it when she does it! She pulls!**

Apparently, she doesn't have problem with her hair to be combed, but she doesn't like it when combing is done by a particular person.

So, in such situations I would expect a sentence structure such as **"I don't like her doing it!"**

But apparently, the sentence **"I don't like it when she does it!"** seems to have the same meaning although the sentence is made up using **"when"**.

So, these two structures both seem to have the same meaning, do they really?

Answer (score 3):

As usual it depends on context: different ways of saying things rarely have **exactly** the same meaning, though they might be interchangeable in many contexts.

Here, I would say that they are usually interchangeable, but *I don't like her combing my hair* is potentially more general.

For example, supposes "her combing my hair" implied something about the relationship between them that the speaker does not like - so it's not the experience specifically of having her hair combed by the other person,  but what it might represent if she did.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the cartoon there is no difference in meaning between the two versions. As they are aimed at a particular individual (the nanny), when spoken out loud the little princess would probably put stress on **"her"** and **"she"**